# hibernate is transforming sequence name having quotes with backtick character

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table with name as "Project" (a table name surrounded by quotes, naming convention in HANA DB).

When I am trying to create a sequence using hibernate with the following code, the enclosing quotes are getting replaced with backticks. I want to have the sequence name enclosed with quotes.

**Code:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="PROJECT_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PROJECT_SEQ",sequenceName="\"MY_SCHEMA\".\"com.project.sequence.Project_SEQ\"",allocationSize=10)
@Column(name="ID", columnDefinition="INTEGER64")
private long id;
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; 
        SQL [select `MY_SCHEMA"."com.project.sequence.Project_SEQ`.nextval from dummy]; 
    nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

**Expectation:**
The below mentioned sequence name should be used by hibernate

```
select "MY_SCHEMA"."com.project.sequence.Project_SEQ".nextval from dummy
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  I would expect that Hibernate would cover escaping with quotes in most use cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its a HANA Database